# What does "Add As Another Boot Drive" do?

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, 22.04, raid

When installing Ubuntu 22.04.3 server, I can select a drive as boot drive which then Ubuntu installer will create a 1GB boot partition on it and then I can select another drive as "Add As Another Boot Drive" which the installer will also create another 1GB boot partition.

Does this mean if one of the drives fail, it will load from the other boot drive? In this case I don't have to do RAID on boot partitions, I presume. Is this the purpose of this feature or is there any other reason for it? If this is what it does, will it automatically switch to other drive if the primary boot drive fails or do I have to do something to boot? Also what would happen if I were to change one of the drives if they become faulty? How can I replace the drive and make Ubuntu to create a boot partition on it again?